# Android OpenCV - Applying math operators on matrices

Tags: android, c++, opencv, matrix, operators

I'm translating some cpp code to android. In cpp, there are overload methods for doing math operators between opencv matrices. It didn't work in android.

cpp code:

```
int thresh = 30, N = 11;
Mat gray0(image.size(), CV_8U), gray;

for (int l = 0; l < N; l++) {

        if (l == 0)
        {
            // apply Canny. Take the upper threshold from slider
            // and set the lower to 0 (which forces edges merging)
            Canny(gray0, gray, 0, thresh, 5);
            // dilate canny output to remove potential
            // holes between edge segments
            dilate(gray, gray, Mat(), Point(-1, -1));
        }
        else
        {
            // apply threshold if l!=0:
            gray = gray0 >= (l + 1) * 255 / N;
        }
}
```

I'm stuck in the `else` section.

Need to write that code in android.
Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: `cv::threshold(gray0, gray, (l+1)*255/N, 255, THRESH_BINARY);` gives same result. [reference](https://github.com/Itseez/opencv/blob/master/samples/tapi/squares.cpp#L69)

Answer (score 1):

Found it in opencv library. The operators are found in `Core.compare`.

Answer: `Core.compare(gray0, new Scalar((l+1) * 255/N), gray, Core.CMP_GE);`